# Promise "Resolve" is convert object to string?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This promise is converting my object to a string

```
cobraCommand() {

  const data = this.getData(localStorage.getItem('BusinessAddress'))

  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    if(data){
      let newData = this.removeEmptyProps(data)
      console.log(newData, "before RESOLVE")
      resolve(newData)
    }
  }).then(function(result) {

    console.log(result + "in THEN");

  }).then(function(result) {
    return result;
  })
}
```

data is an object and removeEmptyProps removes the fields with empty property values.

```
console.log(newData, "before RESOLVE")
```

returns

```
{name: "BusinessAddress"} "before RESOLVE"
```

.

```
console.log(result + "in THEN");
```

returns

```
[object Object]in THEN
```

Comment: You are concatenating the object to a string - just use `console.log(result, "in THEN");` and see your object in console.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you do `object + string` js transform the object into a string to be able to concatenate them. to do that it call [`Object.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) which default to `return "[object Object]"` if you didn't create one in your object

you need to use a `,` between the object and the string if you don't want this call to `toString`

```js
let obj = {}
console.log(obj+"")
console.log(obj.toString())
console.log(obj, "a string")

let objWithToString = {
  toString() {
    return "I have my own to string"
  }
}
console.log("objWithToString.toString() returns :" + objWithToString)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because you're using string concatenation. You're adding a string to an object with the + operator. This results in a string.

Like mentioned in the comments above you can do :

```
console.log(result, "in THEN");
```